# Dynamic Tab containing List View Showing Adjacent Tab List

Tags: android

I'm having one parent Fragment whose class is Scrollbaltab  which contains many dynamic child Fragment whose class is Fragment1 but when I'm scrolling tab "two" it shows tab "one" data and when scroll to tab "three" it shows tab "two" data please help me

```
  //Dynamic Fragment

        public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

            RecyclerViewAdapter  recyclerViewAdapter;

            HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> item = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
            ArrayList  onlineData1 = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList  onlineData2 = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList  onlineData3 = new ArrayList<>();

            String titleName="";

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View inflateView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, null, false);
                RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflateView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

                recyclerView.removeAllViews();
                recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this.getActivity() ,item.get(titleName));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

                //Layout manager for Recycler view
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity() ));
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return inflateView;

            }
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                int tab_position = Scrollbaltab.pos;

                if(onlineData1.isEmpty())
                {
                    onlineData1.clear();
                }
                if(onlineData2.isEmpty())
                {
                    onlineData2.clear();
                }

                if(onlineData3.isEmpty())
                {
                    onlineData3.clear();
                }
                item.clear();


              onlineData1.add("one");
               onlineData1.add("two");
                onlineData1.add("three");


                onlineData2.add("a");
                onlineData2.add("b");
                onlineData2.add("c");

                onlineData3.add("x");
               onlineData3.add("y");
                onlineData3.add("z");

                if(item.get("ONE")==null)
                    item.put("ONE",onlineData1);
                if(item.get("TWO")==null)
                    item.put("TWO",onlineData2);
                if(item.get("THREE")==null)
                    item.put("THREE",onlineData3);

                String [] arr= new String[]{"ONE","TWO","THREE"};

                if(tab_position>=0) {
                    titleName = arr[tab_position];
                }
                // set adpter

                Log.d("values"+tab_position,item.get(titleName).toString());
            }
        }

    //parent Fragment

        public class Scrollbaltab extends AppCompatActivity {

            Toolbar toolbar;
            ViewPager viewPager;
             TabLayout tabLayout;

            ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
            public static int pos=0;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrollbaltab);

                inlizeview();
            }

            private void inlizeview() {

                toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                toolbar.setTitle("scrolling tabbar");
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

                //both are use for set arrow back button in toolbar
                //  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);

                // when click on arrow button of tootbar it finish the current activity
                toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });

                viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                setupViewPager(viewPager);

                tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

                viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                       pos=position;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                    }
                });


            }

            private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
                 adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "ONE");
                adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "TWO");
                adapter.addFragment(new Fragment1(), "THREE");

                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

        }
//view pager adapter
public final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    public final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.e("DD","mFragmentList--"+mFragmentList.get(position));
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return ViewPagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }
    }
```